# Crankshaft Replacement

Tags: shimano, crankset

So I have an old Schwinn Crossfit MTB that Ive loved and had for a long time and recently wanted to fix and upgrade it a bit. I wanted to know about the crankshaft compatibility for it, as ill im able to figure out is that its a 28/38/48 Shimano Tourney, and I was curious if it was compatible with the newer ones of the same brand and name. Yes this is not the best bike, and its also not my only bike, but its more a sentimental thing and a good opportunity to learn more about replacing and figuring out crankshafts for more experience and future work. Thanks so much for your feedback!

Comment: Welcome to the  site! Could you clarify what you mean by "crankshaft"? That's a part of a car engine, not a bike, and it's not quite clear what part of the bike's drivetrain you're talking about. If you can't find the correct technical terms, just describe it in ordinary words and somebody will be able to edit in the right term.

Comment: The horizontal axle that goes through the bike is the Bottom Bracket Axle, and the two legs that connect the axle to the pedals are called Cranks.  There are also Chainrings to connect to and drive the chain - these have the 28/38/48 tooth count.

Comment: If you add a photo showing what you want to replace, we can advise further.

Answer (score 3):

'Crankshaft' if not the name of a bike component and is somewhat ambiguous (some people don't know the proper component names - no offense meant by pointing this out). You could be talking about the bottom bracket, which is the spindle connecting the cranks and its bearings; or you might mean the cranks themselves.

It's probably not worth upgrading components on an older inexpensive bike unless they are worn out or broken. Such a bike can benefit from a good servicing though.

On an older Tourney equipped bike you most likely have a bottom bracket with a square taper spindle that the cranks attach to. The bottom bracket will be an adjustable or cassette type.

On an older bike the bottom bracket may well be worn. If it does not spin freely or there is any play in the bearings it's worn (or needs adjusting). There are some guides available for servicing or replacing [adjustable](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-service-adjustable-type) and [cassette](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-service-cartridge-type) bottom brackets. Be aware you'll need special tools for removing the cranks and adjusting or removing the bracket. If you need to replace a cassette type (or replace an adjustable with a cassette) you need to know the bottom bracket shell with (68 or 73mm) and the spindle length. The shell width and threads are standardized.

If you are thinking about replacing the whole crank, consider replacing just the chainrings as they are the part that wears. If you really want to replace the crank you need one that is for the square taper bottom bracket. Any triple crank for square taper should be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Crank compatibility is largely determined by the bottom bracket interface. As was mentioned, you have a square-taper style bottom bracket, which is not used on higher end cranks these days. You can always replace that bottom bracket with a new outboard-bearing design to fit a modern crank. So, essentially, you can make just about any crank work with your bike provided you're willing to replace the BB.

The more important consideration is what to get and why. Think hard about what it is you most want to improve about the bike. The cranks, in my opinion, make little difference compared to, say, new wheels, or new shifters.